# I need to sort a group of players into teams amd make them as "fair" as possible

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, grouping

I have a group of 9 players with values (skill levels) that I want to sort into 3 teams of 3, such that the total skill level of each team is as close to the same.

For the group,  (1, 1, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 10),  the best arrangement would be (10, 1, 1), (5, 4, 3), (4, 4, 4),  where all 3 teams have a total value of 12.

I grabbed a deck of cards & pulled out 9 cards with those values, sorted them from 10-1, and started dealing them out.  If I just alternate the order of each round of dealing, i.e. first round is left to right, next right to left, etc..  I get (10, 4, 3), (5, 4, 1), (4, 4, 1) for totals of 17, 10, 9.
So I thought, what if I sort the teams after each round?
So I deal the first round, still distributing the players from highest to lowest, then sort ascending, then deal the next round until the cards are all out. This results in (10, 4, 1), (5, 4, 1), (4, 4, 3) for totals of 15, 10, 11. A little better, but not the best arrangement.

I can see that my problem is the 2 lowest scoring players have to get matched with the 1 highest scoring player, but am struggling to find an algorithm that will do that.

Here's my code in php

```
## Get the registered players

  $players = array(1, 1, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 10);
  $total_players = count($players);


## Sort the array by skill level

rsort($players);

## Determine number of teams

$num_teams = ceil($total_players / 3);

## Distribute players on teams

$teams = array();
$team_num = 0;

foreach ($players as $player)
{
  $teams[$team_num]["players"][] = $player;
  $team_num++;

  if ($team_num == $num_teams)
  {
    # reset counter to 0
    $team_num = 0;

    # Sort the teams on total score
    foreach ($teams as $key => $team)
    {
      $total_skill = 0;
      foreach ($team["players"] as $player)
      {
        $total_skill += $player;
      }
      $teams[$key]["total_skill"] = $total_skill;
    }

    aasort_asc($teams, "total_skill");
    $teams = array_values($teams);
  }
}
## Display teams with total scores

echo "<pre>"; print_r($teams); echo "</pre>";
```

There very well may be a solution posted already, but I failed to come up with the right search terms.
I suppose there may be a solution that has nothing to do with players & teams.
Any help or guidance would be most appreciated.
Be Well

I've tried several permutation algorithms. They both blow out memory after about 10 array elements.

Comment: Is it always 9 numeric entries? If not, what is your max? Is it always 3 teams? If not, what do you do with a number values that don't divide evenly (e.g. 8 values into 3 teams)? Are these numeric entries always positive?  Can they be 0? How large can these values be?

Comment: Forgive me, no it will not always be 9, and the team sizes are actually 5 or 4, which will work out with any number over 11, and I'm pretty sure I'll have more than 11.  But it could be some teams of 5, and some teams of 4.   I just used 9 players, teams of 3 for a simpler example.
Entries will always be positive & greater than 0.  The largest number is potentially over 110,000. Most will be 5000 - 30,000.

Comment: Rats. I took too long to edit.  For the example let's say teams of 3 or 2. So 10 values would be 2 teams of 3, and 2 teams of 2.  Number of teams will always be total players divided by max team size, rounded up to the nearest whole number..

Comment: Not all teams same size does complicate matters. Assume team size never varies by more than 1 up or down. Anyway this was my approach when I thought the size was consistent: total all skill levels and divide by team count to get target score per team; sort skill levels as you already have. Start with the largest team size. Continue picking new entries till team is full. Which entry? If current value of team is below average [it always is when it has 0 members], pick from top. If above average, pick from bottom. Keep picking till done.

Comment: Ah, I like that. (I don't see how to pick it & say, "Good Answer!".)   Let me rephrase the way I understood it:   determine a team avg & a player avg. Determine players per team.   For Team 1,  pick from the top. Then since there is now 1 player above player avg, pick from the bottom. Now if the 2 players avgs are > (2*player avg), pick from the bottom again. Otherwise from the top.   I think we could refine this by evaluating the current total compared to the ideal total with one more player,  then picking the closest player to that difference.  Definitely giving this a go. Thank You. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an algorithmic answer.

Assumptions:
 1. Team size max ranges from min to min+1 (equal or one more only)
 2. Skill levels always positive, arbitrarily large

Algorithm - initial/prep:

1. Determine team size min and max.
2. Determine number of teams based on team size min and max.
3. Total all skills into a single sum.
4. Divide total skills by team count to get average skill per team.
5. Divide total skills by # of contestants = average skill each.
6. Sort contestants by skill level.

Algorithm - picking teams:

1. Determine this team's size (min or max) however you like.
2. Take current team's total skill (empty=0 at first).
3. Add highest skill contestant to team.
4. Compare sum of skills in team to average for that many contestants.
5. If this is above average, add next contestant from low skill end.
6. If this is below average, add next from high skill end.
7. Continue 4-6 till team is filled.
8. Continue with further teams (1-7) till done.

Comment: Excellent. This is exactly what I tried & it worked very well with my example data, and with a sample of realistic data.  I did have a thought of trying a refinement.  In steps 5-6, instead of picking from the low/high end,  find the remaining player that brings the current total closest to what it should be for that number of players.  This could, of course leave the last few remaining players with values that could throw the balance off. I'd have to test a larger number of samples with both algorithms to test it.   Again, thanks a bunch for the suggestion.   Be Well